# How to Scan QRCode with xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, qr-code

I'm trying to make a QRCode reader, in my iOS app. I can't get the QR reading value

```
var optionsDefault = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();

var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner()
{
            TopText = "Inquadra il QR Code",
            BottomText = "MyfitnessApp",
};

var scanResult = await scanner.Scan(optionsDefault);
return scanResult.Text;
```

I'm developing on xamarin.ios

Comment: iOS has native QR code scanning - see sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/qrchestra/

Comment: it's too confusing, how could I implement it?

Comment: Now it is better?

Comment: not sure what you mean?  they give you a complete downloadable example.  If you want to use ZXing instead, did you read the docs and do all of the required initialization?  When you say it doesn't work, what specifically do you mean?  Is it throwing an exception or error?  Does the `scanResult` object have a value?  Why are you not specifying the formats you want to scan?

Comment: the scan result object does not return any value when it finds the QR code, the script just stops the scan, with the script I shared.

Comment: while for the qrchestra documentation, I can't find the simple scan of the qr code, I don't know this handout and I can't implement it in my code.